# Small markdown parsing bug in comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

After I voted to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54357/bernoullis-representation-of-eulers-number-i-e-e-lim-x-to-infty-left1), the automatically generated comment

> possible duplicate of [Finding the limit of $n/\sqrt\[n\]{n!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476)

exhibited a small bug. Its source is

```
[Finding the limit of $n/\sqrt\[n\]{n!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476)
```

As you can see there or in my comment below, the markdown link isn't properly parsed. I assume that this is due to the square brackets inside the math environment. In an answer or question field that source works, but apparently not in comments.

**Edit:** Apparently this doesn't have much to do with the math environment, as Hendrik points out in his comment below.

Comment: Here's the link again: [Finding the limit of $n/\sqrt\[n\]{n!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476)

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to TeX: This test comment `[a \[b\] c](http://math.stackexchange.com/)` gives [a \[b\] c](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Right. Thanks! I didn't try much before posting this. I replaced the (tex) tag by the (markdown) tag. This seems more adequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escaped closing bracket `\]` wasn't handled correctly. This is fixed in the next build.

Comment: Okay, this is fixed, thanks! I don't know if it is worth thinking about fixing that without escaped brackets, that is to try and parse things of the form `[test [test]](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476)` correctly. At the moment this gives [test [test]](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28476).

Comment: @Theo: I guess that's by design, see [this answer of balpha on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52312/comment-links-fail-when-next-to-non-whitespace/77093#77093).

Comment: @Hendrik: I see. Thanks a second time!

Comment: FYI, I just reproduced this bug [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39079#comment1095727_39079). I replaced the `\[` and `\]` but to no avail.